# Pull file(s) from separate GIT repository in Bamboo

Tags: git, gradle, repository, bamboo, artifacts

I have a situation where we will have multiple webapps (so for this one we will call it webapp1) that will use a common build script in Bamboo. This script will be part of a separate repository in GIT (something like scripts/Gradle/webapps/script.gradle).

When I do the build (or deployment) in Bamboo, I want to grab the entire webapp1 repository, and just add the .gradle files in the webapps directory of the scripts repository.

At the moment I have the scripts repository coming down into an externals dir (that way when I copy I will ignore the externals dir and any .gradle files), and have managed to get the correct script files into a different artifact (using the location /Externals/Gradle/Webapps and copy pattern **/*.gradle) but when you pull the artifacts back in, they are not in the one directory.

How can I get the .gradle scripts into the root build directory?

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing was pretty much correct.

1) Download main app repository to working directory

2) Download Scripts repository to Externals directory

3) Create the main artifact leaving location blank and copy pattern **/*

4) Create Scripts artifact with the location as /Externals/Gradle/Webapps and copy pattern **/*.gradle (change this to whatever files you want in the artifact)

5) On deployment, after clearing the working dir, create a task that downloads all artifacts to the working directory

6) The scripts are now in the working directory to be used